# How to set document root to load Laravel application using Nginx?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

My site keep showing phpinfo(); when I land on it

- My root should be : `/home/forge/aveniros/public`
- I'm not sure where to set it.
- I decide to configure my settings in : **~/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

---

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name
    default;
    root / home / forge / aveniros / public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    #
    FORGE SSL(DO NOT REMOVE!)# ssl_certificate;#
    ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf - 8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri / /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log /
        var / log / nginx /
        default -error.log error;

    error_page 404 / index.php;

    location~\.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^ (. + \.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run / php5 - fpm.sock; fastcgi_index index.php; include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location~/\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

---

Then, I run `sudo service nginx restart` after I saved.
Nothing seem to take effect.

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong here ?

Comment: leave only one `index index.php;`

Comment: Now I get `No input file specified.` !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Site is working now. Here are my settings :

**File Path : ~/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/aveniros/public;

    #HTTP Authentication Configuartion
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/forge/aveniros/.htpasswd;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your server name to _, currently you are only listening to requests to the name default.

```
server_name  _;
```

Comment: so I can't leave it as default right ? Plus, how to I find out my server name ? Is it the name in linode ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this virtual host

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  project.dev;
root /var/www/directory/project/public;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php/?(.*)$ {

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;     # default of 60s is just too long
    fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;       # default of 60s is just too long

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
location /phpmyadmin {
root /usr/share/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
}
} 
}
```